# Can I use any device that sends a BLE signal?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I am developing android application with BLE. To test the application, I will buy a device that sends a BLE signal. For example, there is a device that finds lost and found objects. There is an app developed for this device. But can I use this device in my own app? Will this device also work for my application?

Answer (score 1):

Different tag finder devices use different technologies and protocols.

Apple's Air Tags, for example, use a combination of Ultra wideband (UWB) and Bluetooth LE (BLE), but it uses proprietary protocols for each mechanism and the UWB channel is encrypted, meaning you cannot use these for your own applications.

Tile tags use BLE, but they also do not use open-standard protocols so these will be difficult to use for your own projects.

Some Minew tags that advertise a finder application are standard BLE beacons and these would work better for your own project.

Regardless of the above, you are always better off just getting standard BLE beacons for a your own app, as you can be confident they will work with open standards and you don't have to reverse-engineer the protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will review the protocols and what you said and research it again. Thank you so much.